# SELinux: command output printed on serial but not on ssh

Tags: ssh, selinux, ping, ifconfig

I am trying to configure SELinux on Poky Linux distro.

I am connecting to the board both on serial and ssh.

Launching ping and ifconfig on ssh the board prints nothing, whereas the same command on serial is printing the correct one.

At first, ping was completely disabled, so I had to patch the netutils SELinux policy (now works correctly).

The command `journalctl -xe | grep "denied"` shows no "denied" for ping neither ifconfig.

How can I fix this issue? Or where should I look further? Maybe a /dev/pts error?

### EDIT 1:

It works properly in `permissive` mode (`enforcing=0`), the issue arises in `enforcing` mode (`enforcing=1`)

Comment: So you neither get an answer nor an error message? The command returns immediately and you get the command prompt again? Other commands like `echo` give output in your `ssh` session? Strange. Please check whether `ping` and `ifconfig` execute a separate binary or busybox, for console and `ssh` session.

Comment: Yes @Philippos , it is almost as you described. For `ping`, the command does not immediately return to the shell but it prints an empty line with a [] (empty character) and hangs (I suppose is actually running the ping command but not printing it). Running `which` for `ifconfig` and `ping` shows the exactly same paths: `/sbin/ifconfig` , `/bin/ping`

Comment: @Philippos, reading the audit log i have  `denied  { read write } for  pid=2016 comm="sh" path="socket:[4586]" dev="sockfs" ino=4586 scontext=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0`, which is similar to the denied shown here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=426658, albeit missing the "ifconfig" command (they may not be related). Other lines are:  `systemd[1]: Incoming private connection from unprivileged client, refusing: Permission denied`